# Unsupported framework error NUnit and MonoDevelop

Tags: nunit, monodevelop

I have latest versions of MonoDevelop(5.10) and NUnit(3.6.1 installed from oficiall NuGet Gallery) and every time I'm trying to run tests I'm getting error

`UnsupportedFrameworkException: Skipped loading assembly ... because it references an unsupported version of the nunit.framework 3.6.1.0`

What can I do about it ?

Comment: MonoDevelop 5.x/6.x integrated Test pad only supports NUnit 2.4.x. You will need to run your 3.x+ tests via the nuint console runner

Comment: Can you tell me how to run test from MonoDevelop using nunit console ?I've tried to run .dll file that I've found in Debug folder (nunit.framework.dll) but it keeps saying that there are no tests to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently trying to run the tests from inside of MonoDevelop, which only supports NUnit through 2.4.8.

You need to install and run the nunit console runner. Use the NUnit.ConsoleRunner nuget package and run nunit3-console, which is contained in the package.

Comment: How to create .dll test file using MonoDevelop so I can run it using nunit-console ?